# How to use jQuery .subscribe()?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, publish-subscribe, struts2-jquery

I've been trying to use `$.subscribe` but it doesn't seem to work. I downloaded a WAR project where it does work but when I use this function in my project it doesn't work. Do I have to download an extra plugin?

Because I couldn't find info about these functions in the jQuery website either, I just found the new `$.Callbacks()` function. The reason I need to use `$.subscribe` is so I can use something like *onBeforeTopic*.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will need [Publish/subscribe plugin](http://www.novasoftware.com/download/jquery/publish-subscribe.aspx).

I stand corrected: you will need [Struts2 jQuery Plugin](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/).

Comment: I'm using struts2-jquery-plugin and I've been able to use everything just fine, except this $.subscribe function, I don't know why, should they be included in this struts2 plugin?

Comment: According to [the documentation](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery-plugin/#Publish/Subscribe_Framework), struts2-jquery-plugin uses publish/subscribe and should therefore include `$.subscribe` on it's own. It could be an issue with order in which you include scripts; i.e. you're trying to use `$.subscribe` before you loaded your plugin. Post your (relevant) code, in your original question so we can figure out what's going wrong :)

Comment: +1. As an additional information: since [version 1.5.0](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/Changelog#1.5.0) Struts2 jQuery plugin uses the lightweight publish/subscribe framework made by Eric Chijioke, once was hosted on the jQuery plugin page, but since the end of 2011 is not available (still one can check the [original plugin page](https://web.archive.org/web/20111030003248/http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jQuerySubscribe) using Wayback Machine. Note: the archived pages usually load slow).

Comment: **Important note**: the up-to-date Struts2 jQuery plugin site is hosted as a project on Google Code, and the project name is [**struts2-jquery**](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/). Another one (last update 2010), also hosted on Google Code, has its project name confusingly named [**struts2-jquery-plugin**](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery-plugin/), which seems to be the original development...

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a bit late to the party but why not just write your own simple pubsub? Check out this article: https://lowbrowcoder.wordpress.com/2015/02/16/pubsub-pattern-in-javascript/

Comment: Link is broken. But any search on this patern will give simples implementations, though I think it's better to write your own too.